# Rails Factory Girl create a list with relation one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have this 2 factories:

```
factory :video do
  name "Elixir 101 class"
  description "A class of elixir"
  descriptor "111111"
  user    
end

sequence :email { |n| "test#{n}@email.com" }

factory :user do
  email FactoryGirl::generate(:email)
  password 'password'
end
```

This relation is "One user have many videos". So user `has_many` videos and Video `belongs_to` User

I'm trying to create a list with videos with `let!(:videos) { create_list(:video, 3) }`, but when Factory is going to create the second video, the validation `Email has already been taken` pop up. What I've to do to create the all 3 videos with the same user or create 3 different user with 3 different emails.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [sequence](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences)

The docs have exactly this example for you:

```
  sequence :email do |n|
    "person#{n}@example.com"
  end
```